# What if I mispronounce words in Shiva tanam stotram?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, shiva-mahimna-stotra

I am mispronouncing it while reading and finding it very tough because of Sanskrit. Will this anger Lord Shiva? I am just trying to worship him.

Comment: I am sure someone who is worshiped by people across cultures and languages, pronunciation and grammar would be the last thing that would disturb him. It's the intent that matters.

Comment: It won't anger him. But it won't yield desired results. Since it is a stotram it won't backfire which happens in case of mantras

Comment: @Carmensandiego is there some thing which is easier to pronounce and I can earn grace of Lord Shiva?

Comment: Surely you can do Rudra Abhishek with help of a pujari and earn Shivji's grace

Answer (score 1):

It is customary to recite Kshama Prarthana shloka following the moola Stotra, a plea for forgiveness incase of any misgivings that occurred during the recitation . In this way one is relieved from the guilt , by surrendering it thru a **genuine** kshama prarthana to Bhagwan who is ever an ocean of mercy , (instead of holding on to it and brooding over)

Some shlokas

> करचरणकृतं वाक्कायजं कर्मजं वा
> श्रवणनयनजं वा मानसं वाऽपराधम्।
> विहितमविहितं वा सर्वमेतत् क्षमस्व
> जय जय करुणाब्धे श्रीमहादेव शम्भो॥
> Whatever Sins have been Committed by Actions Performed by my Hands and Feet, Produced by my Speech and Body, Or my Works,
> 2: Produced by my Ears and Eyes, Or Sins Committed by my Mind (i.e. Thoughts),
> 3: While Performing Actions which are Prescribed (i.e. duties prescribed by tradition or allotted duties in one's station of life), As Well as All other Actions which are Not explicitly Prescribed (i.e. actions done by self-judgement, by mere habit, without much thinking, unknowingly etc); Please Forgive Them All,
> 4: Victory, Victory to You, O Sri Mahadeva Shambho, I Surrender to You, You are an Ocean of Compassion

> यदक्षरपदभ्रष्टं मात्राहीनं तु यद्भवेत्।
> तत्सर्वं क्षम्यतां देव नारायण नमोऽस्तु ते॥
> विसर्गबिन्दुमात्राणि पदपादाक्षराणि च।
> न्यूनानि चातिरिक्तानि क्षमस्व पुरुषोत्तम॥
> For all those mistakes in letter, phrase, and phonetics that may have occurred in my chanting, forgive me Lord Narayana .For any defect in my pause, intonation, or pronunciation of alphabet, word or phrase, and any other mistake,Forgive me Lord Maheshvara

> **Anyatha Sharanam Nasti Tvameva Sharanam Mamaa , Tasmat Karunya Bhavane, Raksha Raksha Maheshwara**
> I don’t have  any other protection   and you are  my only  protection
> And so with kindness   Protect, protect me   oh great  God

> कायेन वाचा मनसेन्द्रियैर्वा बुद्ध्याऽऽत्मना वा प्रकृतेः स्वभावात्।
> करोमि यद्यत् सकलं परस्मै नारायणायेति समर्पयामि
> Whatever I do either by body, speech, mind or sensory organs, either with my personal knowledge or natural trait, I surrender and submit all to that to supreme divine Narayana.

> अपराधसहस्राणि क्रियन्तेऽहर्निशं मया।
> तानि सर्वाणि हे देव क्षमस्व पुरुषोत्तम 
> Oh great god, I commit thousands of offences routinely, So  please pardon all those mistakes

Answer (score 0):

see

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45768/12489

if you just want to express Bhakti - pronunciation and even grammar doesn't matter.